# How to access 'Resize Table' of 'Table Design' tab in excel with Open XML SDK in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to write to an existing excel template (.xlsx) and saving it as a new file using Open XML SDK in .NET C#. I have a requirement to change the table design and resize the table programmatically. I'm not able to access the 'Resize Table' property using Open XML.
Manually we can access it by going to 'Table Design' tab and then selecting ' Resize Table'. Please refer to the below screenshot
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- First Get Your table By name ( if just one table you can get the
  first)
- then Update the reference ( size of the table) and
- save the workSheet.

the table size refrenace is just a string  ex. A1:H5
you need to change the H5 to H15 to resize the table to add 10 rows more :)

**Just Sample code**

```
 var tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.Where(table=>table.Table.DisplayName== "Your table name").FirstOrDefault();
    // OR var tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault();
     if (tableDefinitionPart != null)
      {
         UpdateTableDefinitionPart(tableDefinitionPart, newTotalRows);
      }
            workSheet.Save();
```

---

```
public void UpdateTableDefinitionPart(TableDefinitionPart tableDefinitionPart, uint rowsCount)
 {
        var tableSize = tableDefinitionPart.Table.Reference;
        string newSize = tableSize.UpdateRowsTo(rowsCount);
        tableDefinitionPart.Table.Reference = newSize;
        tableDefinitionPart.Table.AutoFilter.Reference = newSize;
  }

*************************************************************************************
 public static string UpdateRowsTo(this StringValue tableReference, uint rows)
  {
            string result = tableReference.Value.Trim();
            var parts = result.Split(':');
            Regex regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
            Match match = regex.Match(parts[1]);
            result = $"{parts[0]}:{match.Value}{rows}";
            return result;
   }

OR
***************************************************************************************
        public static string UpdateRowsTo2(this StringValue tableReference, uint rows)
        {
            string result = tableReference.Value.Trim();
            int index = result.Length - 1;
            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) && Char.IsDigit(result[--index]))
            {
            }

            result = result.Substring(0, index + 1) + rows;
            return result;
        }
```